# Как правильно реализовать работу с множественными запроса?

Tags: android, requests

Не уверен правильно ли задал вопрос, но суть в чем...

Есть приложение где имеется более 30 разных запросов.

Все запросы реализованы в одном отдельном классе с конструктором, каждый как отдельный метод, с помощью okhttp.

По итогу в `onFailure` или же в `onResponse` результат обрабатывается по разному:

Например:

- `Activity1 - > запрос -> onsuccess -> act1.finish();`

В `Activity1 - public static act1 = this;`

- Или же `Activity2 - > запрос -> onsuccess -> view1.visible=Gone`;

В `Activity2 -> public static view1 = view;`

И т.п.....

Вопрос: как грамотно и правильно реализовать эту схему взаимодействия...?

Comment: можно все запросы скинуть в один класс, и к нему обращаться по нужной вам схеме

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Примерно так же, как вы действуете с onResponse и onFailure, только создайте свой интерфейс. Если каждый запрос это отдельный объект, то создайте в нем поле, содержащее реализацию интерфейса. Примерно так:

```
//описываем интерфейс, общий для всех запросов. T - тип данных, которые вернет запрос
    public interface Callback<T>{
        void onSuccess(T res);
        void onError(Exeption e);
    }

//предположим, что у нас запрос возвращает строку
public class Query{

    //сохраняем колбэк в свойстве
    private Callback<String> callback = null    
    public Query(Callback<Strong> callback){
         this.callback = callback
    }

    @Override
    void onResponse(Call call, Response response){
        //когда выполнили запрос - вызываем реакцию из коллбэка
        if(callback != null){
            callback.onSuccess(responseToString(res))
        }
    }
    @Override
    void onFailure(Call call, IOException e){
        if(callback != null){
            callback.onError(e)
        }
    }


}
//говорим активити реализовывать наш коллбек и передаем эту самую активити в запрос как коллбэк
public class MyActivivty extends MyActivity implements Callback<String>{
   @Override
   public void onCLick(v: View){
       Query q = Query(this);
       q.exec()
   }
   @Override
   public void onSuccess(String res){
        //обрабатываем ответ
   }
   @Override
   public void onError(Exeption e){
        //обрабатывает ошибку
   }
}
```